# Modify function to evaluate all values on row

Tags: python, pandas

**Test data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
   {'AAA' : [4,5,6,7,9,10], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40,11,10],'CCC' : [100,50,25,10,10,11],'DDD' : [100,50,25,10,10,11]});
thresh = 10
```

**My function:**

```
def closeCols2(df):
    for k1,k2 in combinations(df.keys(),2):
        if abs(df[k1] - df[k2]) < thresh:
            return max(df[k1],df[k2])
```

This gives me the following output showing the max value of a row if two columns are within thresh:

```
df2.apply(closeCols2, axis=1)

0    10
1    50
2    30
3    10
4    11
5    10
dtype: int64
```

But columns `DDD` (100) and `CCC` (100) on row 1 also have values within `thresh` and these are not being evaluated.  How do I modify my function to capture this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the function returns as soon as it finds an absolute difference less than the defined `thresh`. So the first time the condition is met in the first row for columns 'AAA' (4) and 'BBB' (10) it returns the value (10) and stops the execution without even evaluating the next columns. I don't know exactly what you want to do, but you may try to adapt your function like this.

```
def closeCols2(df):
    max_value = None
    for k1,k2 in combinations(df.keys(),2):
        if abs(df[k1] - df[k2]) < thresh:
            if max_value is None:
                max_value = max(df[k1],df[k2])
            else:
                # Max of the max
                max_value = max(max_value, max(df[k1],df[k2]))
    return max_value 

df2.apply(closeCols2, axis=1)

# 0    100
# 1     50
# 2     30
# 3     10
# 4     11
# 5     11
```